# applying modern standards / morals to a past era

Tags: time

Is there a word for "applying modern standards / morals to a past era"?  Something like "anachronism" but not quite.  An example of this would be to criticize a public figure from centuries ago for owning slaves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Presentism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentism_%28literary_and_historical_analysis%29) seems to be what you're looking for.

Definition [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presentism).